Running cells with 'Python 3.8.13' requires the ipykernel package in Google Cloud Editor
I am running into this issue when using Google editor:

Running cells with 'Python 3.8.13' requires the ipykernel package.
Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment

I run the following command python3.10 -m pip install ipykernel

I also tried python -m pip install ipykernel -U --force-reinstall

did you restart your kernel after install?

yes I did still gett the same error @FreePalestine
